# Android Admob advert in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, admob

Is there a way to add an admob advert to a PreferenceActivity? How to?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you can also do is to create a custom Preference that can be easily added to any preferences screen.

Add a layout file called ad_layout.xml to your res/layout folder that will be filled later by AdMob.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">  
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a class called AdPreference like that:

```
package com.example.adpreference;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AdPreference extends Preference {

    public AdPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super    (context, attrs, defStyle);}
    public AdPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}
    public AdPreference(Context context) {super(context);}

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        // this will create the linear layout defined in ads_layout.xml
        View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

        // the context is a PreferenceActivity
        Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();

        // Create the adView
        AdView adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, "<your add id>");

        ((LinearLayout)view).addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(request);     

        return view;    
    }
}
```

Now in the preference xml file you can just add add any position you like (at the top or in between any other preferences ).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...

    <com.example.adpreference.AdPreference android:layout="@layout/ad_layout"/>

    ...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: and also we need to destroy adView!?

Comment: This not work. It throw "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" error

Comment: Everytime I scroll away from the adView it removes it and when I scroll back it will reload it.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, a `PreferenceActivity` is just a sub-class of `ListActivity` and, as with `ListActivity`, you can specify your own custom layout so long as it contains a `ListView` with an ID of `android.R.id.list`.  So create whatever XML layout file you need containing a `ListView` and an `AdView` and use that layout for the `PreferenceActivity`.

Answer (score 16):

Dan Dyer's answer is correct. I would like to elaborate a bit, just to clarify by example.You can use a layout like this (called config.xml under res/layout).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xxxx" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
            myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity that extends PreferenceActivity you write something like this in the onCreate method;

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.config);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is some changes to **P.Melch** answer in 
Adpreference class is like below **(because its not working with latest google play ads library):**

```
    public class AdPreference extends Preference {

    public AdPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super    (context, attrs, defStyle);}
    public AdPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}
    public AdPreference(Context context) {super(context);}

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        // this will create the linear layout defined in ads_layout.xml
        View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

        // the context is a PreferenceActivity
        Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();

        AdView   adView = new AdView(getContext());
        adView.setAdUnitId("<your ad id>");
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        ((LinearLayout)view).addView(adView);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
viewGroup.addView(new AdView(...));
```

Comment: You should add more information to your answer. I have no idea where I should place this, what this does etc

Comment: @SuperThomasLab you should place it in your PreferenceActivity. In onCreate, for instance. I thought it's obvious. What this does? Well, read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a separate layout for ad and Add it to **`preference_screen.xml`** as **`PreferenceCategory`**.
You can see the clear picture in the attached images [*layout*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAzBP.png)

[***preferenceScreen***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6yc3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the proposed approach, but faced problem regarding placing the banner at the top and with padding issues. So, i used a different approach and interested to share with you. I was working on a preference activity, although it has been deprecated but i had to work on it for some reason instead of changing to androidx preference library.

Here are the following steps:

1. Get the parent of preference activity.

   ```
   LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) 
   findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
   ```
2. Create a xml file named banner_ad.xml.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Inflate the layout.

   ```
   LinearLayout adViewLayout = (LinearLayout) 
   LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.banner_ad,root,false);
   AdView adView = adViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.adview);
   ```
4. Load add.

   ```
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
           .addTestDevice(device_id)
           .build();
   adView.loadAd(adRequest);
   ```
5. Add layout view as a child of root view. In my case i used this below toolbar at index 1.

   ```
   root.addView(adViewLayout,1);
   ```