# Android How can i add ads in listactivity?

Tags: android, listactivity, ads

I tried both admob and mobfox. However, there is no advertisement in list activity.

```
RelativeLayout adslayout;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listlayout,R.id.txtmesajlar , messages);
mobfoxView = new MobFoxView(this, publisherId, true, true);
setListAdapter(adapter);
adslayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adslayout);
adslayout.addView(mobfoxView);
```

From Logcat: Exception is java lang NullPointerException.

When i tried same codes in my other activity, i put  mobfoxview in linearlayout and ads banner succesfully added. Is listactivity ignore advertisement or there is some error from me?

listlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/adslayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"></RelativeLayout>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtmesajlar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@color/White" android:textSize="18sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:drawingCacheQuality="auto" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/listenvelop"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mc.bayrammesajlari/com.mc.bayrammesajlari.BayramActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at com.mc.bayrammesajlari.BayramActivity.onCreate(BayramActivity.java:52)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-25 12:11:59.925: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post your XML that contains these two Views

Comment: NullPointerException isn't enough.  Which line threw the NullPointerException?  What's the stacktrace?

Comment: I do not use mobfoxview in xml. I added view with code. there is no mobfoxview in xml. I just use this:   <activity android:name="com.mobfox.sdk.InAppWebView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"/> in android manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put ads next to your list, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5019834/5171) explain how to do it (PreferenceActivity is just a subclass of ListActivity so the solution is the same).

If you want the ads to actually appear *in* the list (as rows that scroll with the rest of the list content), I previously wrote [this article](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/05/09/embedding-admob-adverts-in-android-listviews/) about how I achieved this for AdMob.

Comment: I m confused. I have a one listlayout.xml which is used by here: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listlayout,R.id.txtmesajlar , mesajlar); listlayout.xml 's main element is linearlayout and it contains textview and relative layout. Do i need to add listview in it or i completely remove listlayout.xml and create new .xml which its main element is listview?

Comment: @Dunker If you define your own layout for the `ListActivity` it needs to include a `ListView` called `@android:id/list` so that Android knows where the list goes in relation to the other widgets (such as your ads).

Comment: Thank you for your support. I really attempt to solve. I created my own layout for listactivity design. Therefore, i do not use android's default list. However, i didn't create any listview but it works. All items list in properly. I created textview for list item's attributes like color, text size etc. I created relativelayout for holding advertisement. Therefore, why can i need to create listview for? I did something wrong but i can't solve. Clearly, textview defines listitem's color size and logo and advertisement fails in relativelayout.

Comment: I solve it. Thank you for your support but i wonder about something. I didn't create listview in layout but it works. I suppose if the objects strings, there is no problem but if the view is coming like ads it throws an exception.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you are/were doing from the incomplete code in the question.  We may be referring to different layouts.  If you put the ads *in* the list rather than next to the list then you wouldn't need a custom layout to hold your `ListView`, you'd only need the layout that is used to render each row.

Comment: Yes, i understand but i have a new problem. When i add ads in list, list's itemclick is disabled. İs there a way to use both of them's action in same layout? My actual aim is to put ads top in listactivity (not every single row). I think i use your class to do that.