# Fixed ad at the bottom of PrefereceActivity

Tags: android, admob, preferenceactivity

I have a PreferenceActivity for a LiveWallpaper and have used the solution here ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019834/android-admob-advert-in-preferenceactivity)) to create an Admob ad. It works, but the ad disappers when the user scrolls up or down and loads again when it comes into view. Is there a way so that the ad always stays at the bottom (or top) of the activity (like in a regular activity)?

Comment: Kindly provide the XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
((LinearLayout)view).addView(adView);
```

Try setting the layoutParam like

```
adView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```

OR Change the layout like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And code part would be like this:

```
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new ToastAdListener(this));
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```